# Trouble auto labelling buttons from database then centering them in a frame

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

```
class ManageExistingColleaguePanel(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    con = sqlite3.connect("hs_audit.sqlite")
    con.text_factory = str
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT engineer FROM T1")
    myList = [r[0] for r in cur.fetchall()]
    con.close()
    main_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()
    for n in range(0, len(myList)):
        main_sizer.Add(wx.Button(self, wx.CENTER, label = str(myList[(n)]), size = (200, 35)))
    main_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()
    self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
```

I have been trying to get a column of buttons centered in the frame labeled with the contents of a column in a mysqlite3 table.
I can get the buttons in a column all labelled but can't get them centered.  I have tried loads of different combinations to get this right, but get errors regarding undefined label or size variables.  I can get a centered column of buttons but then I am unable to label them.

Any help please this is driving me mad.

Answer (score 0):

At last.  Can't seem to get the hang of the wxpython sizer syntax's.

Anyways here was the answer.

```
class ManageExistingColleaguePanel(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    con = sqlite3.connect("hs_audit.sqlite")
    con.text_factory = str
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT engineer FROM T1")
    myList = [r[0] for r in cur.fetchall()]
    con.close()
    main_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()
    for n in range(0, len(myList)):
        main_sizer.Add(wx.Button(self, label=str(myList[(n)]), size=(200, 35)), 0, wx.CENTER)
    main_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()
    self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
```